# flex mobile project : using Blazeds to access data from java class

Tags: java, blazeds, flex4.5

I know how to create a flex web application that uses blazeds for back end  data connectivity.
Now I need to use blazeds in flex mobile application for accessing data from java classes. I am searching it in internet for two days but I didnt find any solutions. Please help me to use blazeds in flex mobile app

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Do you have an AIR application running on mobile which should connect to a BlazeDS server? It's hard to guess.

Comment: I have one xml file stored in server. I want to access the file only if the file is modified. I have created a flex mobile project in flex 4.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [Coenraets](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/08/flex-spring-mobile-test-drive-learn-the-best-way-to-build-java-backed-ios-android-and-playbook-apps/) blog you have a couple of examples relates to connection mobile flex applications to a java backend (both remoting and messaging).

In order to detect if the file was modified you can have a timer in java checking for that at a specified interval. When detecting any changes you can send a message to your Flex application using the messaging services from BlazeDS.