# flex 4.5.1:Access file from server

Tags: blazeds, flex4.5

I am working on flex mobile project using flex 4.5.1.  I want to get data from file (which is placed on server) only if the file is modified.  I think I can use blazeds for this purpose, But I dont know how to do this. I am searching it in internet. please guide me

Comment: possible duplicate of [flex mobile project : using Blazeds to access data from java class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606153/flex-mobile-project-using-blazeds-to-access-data-from-java-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/AccessingData/WSbde04e3d3e6474c46c45e7b4120d413dc14-8000.html

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/flex-using-item-renderers

hope the above links would help you.